# XCTestCase runsForEachTargetApplicationUIConfiguration not working as expected

Tags: xcode, xcuitest

Overriding this method of XCTestCase to return true should run the tests once for each UI configuration an app supports. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/3867004-runsforeachtargetapplicationuico)

What I get is this (screenshot) having 4 languages3 iPhone orientations, light/dark mode:

- far more Italian tests than other languages
- only landscape right is triggered, never landscape left

Expectation: exactly 1 test for every language, orientation, light/dark mode

I tried to narrow down the problem: removing the landscape right orientation will make the landscape left orientation work. But then also the count still is wrong.

Is there more documentation about this? Or might this simply be a bug? Any hint is welcome. Thanks in advance.

[image]